# Pushing an array of object with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Should not parameters(product and quantity) be replaced with the arguments("bread" and 5) and become object keys? instead arguments are in object values, I am confused is not parameters just placeholders of arguments?

```
const cart = [];

 const addtoCart = function (product, quantity) {
  cart.push({ product, quantity });
  
};

addtoCart('bread', 5);
console.log(cart); //returns {"product": "bread","quantity": 5}
```

Comment: They are replaced. Your code is doing exactly what it should do; what did you expect? `cart.push({ product, quantity });` means `cart.push({product: product, quantity: quantity});` — in other words it **creates an object** with property names and values taken from the names of the parameters and their values.

Comment: the code inside the push function is shorthand for this `{ product: product, quantity: quantity }`

Comment: I expected {"bread": undefined,"5": undefined}

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect. See the above comments.

Comment: Did you want `cart.push({ [product]: quantity });` instead?

Comment: @IWNGU why do you expect `undefined`? You've passed in the correct parameters...

Comment: Now I get it thank you all very much, I was confused because with arrays parameters are replaced with values, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your key around square brackets and a colon after like

```
cart.push({ [product]: quantity });
```